# How to render fields from User profile using user reference?

Tags: entities, users

I have content type Team in which user reference is used.
Now I need to get the user profile fields based on the user reference in the content type.

**Example** - In team content type i am adding 1 user using user reference field and based on that user reference selection i need to pull out gender of that selected user and load in a gender drop-down.

Is there any module for this or any custom coding required?

Comment: do you need this information in the node edit or view page?

Comment: I need this information on node edit/add.